# HTML Email: How to make image overlapping border?

Tags: html, css, zurb-foundation

I'm using Foundation for Emails and want to position a horizontal ruler `<hr>` below the menu-item and the NILE-Logo:

[image: Nominal Situation]

I could achieve this with moving hr `hr { margin-top: -1rem; }` .

Unfortunately (according to [Litmus](https://litmus.com/blog/hotmail-and-outlook-com-drop-support-for-margin)) CSS property margin is not supported in Outlook Mail Client and it is displayed like this:

[image]

```
<center class="header float-center" align="center" data-parsed="">
  <table align="center" class="menu float-center">
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <table>
            <tbody>
              <tr>
                <th class="menu-item float-center">
                  <%= link_to t('view.nav.women'), seo_url(Spree::Taxon.new_in) %>
                </th>
                <th class="menu-item float-center">

                  <%= link_to t('view.nav.men'), seo_url(Spree::Taxon.new_in) %>
                </th>
                <th class="menu-item float-center">
                  <%= link_to root_path do %>
                    <img src="nile_logo.png" alt="NILE Logo" width="120px" height="70px" />
                  <% end %>
                </th>
                <th class="menu-item float-center">
                  <%= link_to t('view.nav.stores'), page_path('stores') %>
                </th>
                <th class="menu-item float-center">
                  <%= link_to t('view.nav.lifestyle'), page_path('lifestyle') %>
                </th>
              </tr>
            </tbody>
          </table>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</center>
<hr>
```

My second attempt is to use rowspan with border-bottom to table cells instead of hr but the image spans the row so that the border is not overlapped.

```
<center class="header float-center" align="center" data-parsed="">
  <table align="center" class="menu float-center">
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <table>
            <tbody>
              <tr>
                <th class="border menu-item float-center">
                  <%= link_to t('view.nav.women'), seo_url(Spree::Taxon.new_in) %>
                </th>
                <th class="border menu-item float-center">
                  <%= link_to t('view.nav.men'), seo_url(Spree::Taxon.new_in) %>
                </th>
                <th class="menu-item float-center">
                  <%= link_to root_path do %>
                    <img src="https://www.nile.ch/nile_logo.png" alt="NILE Logo" width="120px" height="70px" />
                  <% end %>
                </th>
                <th class="border menu-item float-center">
                  <%= link_to t('view.nav.stores'), page_path('stores') %>
                </th>
                <th class="border menu-item float-center">
                  <%= link_to t('view.nav.lifestyle'), page_path('lifestyle') %>
                </th>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>&nbsp;</td>
                <td>&nbsp;</td>
                <td>&nbsp;</td>
                <td>&nbsp;</td>
              </tr>
            </tbody>
          </table>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</center>
```

What alternatives do I have to position the horizontal ruler accurate to the layout-mockup below the logo-image?

Comment: make 1 div after your menu. and use `z-index:-1`

Comment: it doesn't solve the problem positioning the div without using margin (e.g. margin-top: -1rem). the div will be pushed away from image instead be overlapped.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could solve it with making 3 table rows, rowspan=3 to the logo-image-td and add border-bottom on the last td row without the one td with logo.